# How to get session cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to get this cookie from javascript code but it doesn't show in the console.

```
document.cookie
```

I checked in chrome settings cookie and it shows all of its data and the cookie expiration says **Expires:  When the browsing session ends**

and also it says

> Send for: Secure connections only

Is there any way to get that cookie please let me know

[image: Please find the below image]

Answer (score 10):

A session cookie is just a cookie without an explicit expiry date. It expires when the browser is closed. This has absolutely no bearing on if a cookie shows up in `document.cookie` or not.

The only reason a cookie would not show up there would be if it was marked [`httponly` which explicitly bans browser-side JavaScript from accessing it](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly). In that case, there is no way to access it from JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: Is there any way to get it through template engine or through java and also it says `Accessible to script: No (HttpOnly)`

Comment: Assuming you mean server side Java, then the standard methods your framework has for reading cookies should work fine.

Comment: "Accessible to script: No (HttpOnly) " — That confirms my assumption.

Comment: could you suggest code for JAVA to read these type of cookies

Comment: Can we retrieve those from template engine... we are using freemarker template engine...

Comment: No. I don't use Java on the server side. I don't know how you are running Java on the server side (there's JSP, there's servlets, there's a host of frameworks (MVC and otherwise)). Read the documentation for the libraries you are using to talk HTTP. Reading cookies is basic stuff so they will cover it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion will try for it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can define the following property in application.properties:

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=false
```

Then you will be able to read JSESSIONID from `document.cookie`